# Generating sequence of dates

Tags: r

i would like to generate sequence of dates with next code:

```
vm1=strptime("2000-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
vm2=strptime("2011-12-31 23:55:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
vm3=seq(vm1, vm2, by = min(300))
```

The problem is that on some specific date program changes time zone and omits part of generated data. For example:

```
vm3[24500:24510]
```

I would appreciate any help or instructions.

Comment: Thank you Richie, by adding tz UTC now works fine, previously i used CET and it looks that this was the problem.

Comment: If @richie-cotton answer solved your problem, the best way to show it to other users and to thank him is to upvote his answer and to accept it with the green check mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That section of `vm3` looks fine to me (UK locale, `GMT/BST` time zone).  Consider forcing your dates to be in universal time, and then correcting to your local time zone later on.

```
vm1=strptime("2000-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
vm2=strptime("2011-12-31 23:55:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
vm3=seq(vm1, vm2, by = "300 mins")
any(is.na(vm3)) #FALSE
```

BTW, you want a `by` argument of `"300 mins"`, not `min(300)`.  `min` is the minimum function; it has nothing to do with minutes.