# Generating time only sequences

Tags: r

Is there a way to generate time-only sequences in R? I don't want to use dates; I need to generate all the times from 12:00:00 to 13:00:00 every 5 minutes.

`seq()` won't work here:

```
interval = min * 60
seq(from = times('12:00:00'), to = times('13:00:00'), by = interval)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a specific sequence of date/times in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009301/creating-a-specific-sequence-of-date-times-in-r)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Generating sequence of dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706330/generating-sequence-of-dates?rq=1)

Comment: @Thomas The question is about time-only series. No dates.

Comment: The principle is exactly the same, though.

Comment: @Thomas If you call generating time series sequences the 'same principle' there are dozens of other questions on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works almost verbatim with chron:

```
> library(chron)
> min <- 5
> interval <- min / (60 * 24)
> seq(from = times('12:00:00'), to = times('13:00:00'), by = interval)
 [1] 12:00:00 12:05:00 12:10:00 12:15:00 12:20:00 12:25:00 12:30:00 12:35:00
 [9] 12:40:00 12:45:00 12:50:00 12:55:00 13:00:00
```

Alternately `interval` could be specified like this:

```
interval <- times("00:05:00")
```